# Build Magento module from the command line

Tags: magento2, module, magento-1

looking at the output of mage shell script it seems that it is possible to build a module via the command line. Does anyone have and idea how i can do it?

```
Connect commands available:
===========================
.....

package              Build Package       
package-dependencies Show package dependencies
package-prepare      Show installation information of package

......
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "build"?

Comment: Create an archive.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun

Comment: No, you can't. And there is no such functionality in n98-magerun too.

Comment: Ok, i've tried Mavento(mavento.bbe-consulting.de/‎), but it looks like it is not capable of assembling an archive either.Does anybody knows a tool that might do trick?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evgeni,

Currently there is no way of packaging an extension directly from the command line, also regarding the `./mage package` command

```
Connect commands available:
===========================
.....

package              Build Package       
package-dependencies Show package dependencies
package-prepare      Show installation information of package

......
```

The command names can be misleading the package in particular is designed to be ran on the package.xml which contains a module information, it basically has the opposite effect of what you are trying achieve.

Currently I don't think there is any solution to package extensions directly from the command line, I supposed that you could create a script that does this but it would be hard to specify all the extension files, dependencies and information that is required to generated a valid Connect extension package.

Comment: Thank you, Allan!I will try to write a bash script for this kind of task.

Answer (score 1):

It's necessary to have a prepared package.xml in var/connect folder for your package. After that it's possible to run command

`./mage package /absolute/path/to/your/magento/var/connect/package.xml`

That command will create tgz package under var/connect.

I'm myself aiming for creating packages with Bamboo CI. It means I need to add package.xml to git and prepare package info in Magento backend (updated version, release notes etc). After that I commit package.xml and push it. Bamboo CI would pick it up and create a package. I can try it out shortly. I'll let you know if it works fine this way.

Comment: Now I've written a whole long blog post about making Bamboo creating tgz packages for you. Please see here http://measure9.varkel.net/2014/07/continuous-integration-server-to-package-magento-extension/